# Создать список из двух других по условию на Scala

Tags: scala

Есть класс:

```
case class Person (age: Int, name: String)
```

Есть два списка:

```
val classRoom1 = List(Person(14, "Jimm"),Person(14, "Jack"), Person(13, "Ricky"))
val classRoom2 = List(Person(14, "Jimm"),Person(14, "Jack"), Person(13, "Ricky"), Person(13,"Susan"), Person(16, "Jack"))
```

Нужно выбрать по полю name из второго списка выбрать те объекты, которых нету в в первом и создать из них третий список.

```
val classRoom3 = List(Person(13,"Susan"))
```

Как это сделать, придерживаясь функционального стиля?

Comment: Если только по полю `name`, то почему у тебя Джек попал в третий список, хотя он присутствует в первом?

Comment: Прошу прощения, ошибся. конечно  val classRoom3 = List(Person(13,"Susan")).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Позвольте предложить простое(в плане кода) решение в лоб:

```
val classRoom1 = List(Person(14, "Jimm"),Person(14, "Jack"), Person(13, "Ricky"))
val classRoom2 = List(Person(14, "Jimm"),Person(14, "Jack"), Person(13, "Ricky"), Person(13,"Susan"), Person(16, "Jack"))

val classRoom3 = classRoom2.filterNot(p => classRoom1.exists(_.name == p.name))

println(classRoom3)    //List(Person(13,Susan))
```

Сложность тут `n*m`.
Если не устроит, можно обернуть в мапки и добиться линейной сложности. Но код будет более запутанным.

Comment: Спасибо, а решение то было простым)

Answer (score 0):

В случае небольших списков подойдет такой вариант:
`classRoom2.diff(classRoom2.intersect(classRoom1))`

При больших же списках лучше сделать что-то типа такого:

```
abstract class Keyable[B] {
  def uniq: B
}

case class Person(age: Int, name: String) extends Keyable[(Int, String)] {
  override def uniq = (age, name)
}

implicit class SeqExtKey[C](val seq: List[Keyable[C]]) extends AnyVal {

  def diffE(anotherSeq: List[Keyable[C]]) = {
    val firstMap = seq.groupBy(_.uniq)
    val secondMap = anotherSeq.groupBy(_.uniq)

    secondMap.keySet.diff(firstMap.keySet).flatMap(secondMap.get).flatten.toList
  }
}

val classRoom1 = List(Person(14, "Jimm"), Person(14, "Jack"), Person(13, "Ricky"))
val classRoom2 = List(Person(14, "Jimm"), Person(14, "Jack"), Person(13, "Ricky"), Person(13, "Susan"), Person(16, "Jack"))

val diff = classRoom1.diffE(classRoom2)

println(diff)
```

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/Me1c4S5/0

Comment: Спасибо) Но это не по полю "name". А мне нужно сравнение именно по полю "name". В примере третьего списка я ошибся, он должен выглядеть  так val classRoom3 = List(Person(13,"Susan")). Ведь "name" Jack есть в первом списке.